# UpdateView with form_class removes named submit input from POST

Tags: python, django, forms, post, form-submit

I want to know which submit input was clicked by the user. The submitted form goes to an `UpdateView` that uses a `ModelForm`. I've added the name attribute to the submit inputs but when I do `if 'approve' in self.request.POST:` within `get_context_data()` it's False. I overridden `def post()` and `approve` is a key in the `POST` dict. Is there a way to get `approve` or `decline` to show in `get_context_data()`?.

At a guess it has to be something to do with the ModelForm being involved but is there a way to get it through without overriding the post method or should I just except it?

FYI, I've omitted some code that was just bloat and not relevant to the issue. Apologies if there's something in there that doesn't make sense.

**models.py**

```
class Definition(DefinitionInfo):
    SEV3 = 'info'
    SEV2 = 'warning'
    SEV1 = 'danger'
    sup_sevs = (
        ('', 'Please select'),
        (SEV3, 'Sev3'),
        (SEV2, 'Sev2'),
        (SEV1, 'Sev1'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    resolution = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    sup_sev = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=sup_sevs, null=False, blank=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DefinitionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Definition
        fields = ['title', 'sup_sev', 'description', 'resolution']
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'resolution': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class DefinitionUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Definition
    context_object_name = 'definition'
    form_class = DefinitionForm
    template_name_suffix = '_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('definitions:index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            print(f'Post data: {self.request.POST}')
        return context
```

**update_form.html**

```html
<form id="defForm" class="container-sm w-50" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form.delete }}
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-dark text-light" id="{{ form.title.auto_id }}" name="{{ form.title.html_name }}" placeholder="Enter title here..." value="{{ form.title.value|default_if_none:'' }}">
        <label class="form-label" for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}">Title</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        {{ form.sup_sev }}
        <label class="form-label" for="{{ form.sup_sev.id_for_label }}">Severity</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
    {{ form.description }}
    <div id="description" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-dark text-light d-inline-block" style="white-space: pre-wrap;" contentEditable>{{ form.description.value|default_if_none:'' }}</div>
    <label class="form-label" for="{{ form.description.id_for_label }}">Description</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
    {{ form.resolution }}
    <div id="resolution" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-dark text-light d-inline-block" style="white-space: pre-wrap;" contentEditable>{{ form.resolution.value|default_if_none:'' }}</div>
    <label class="form-label" for="resolution">Resolution</label>
  </div>
  <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
    <input id="decline" class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="decline" type="submit" value="Decline">
    <input id="approve" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="approve" type="submit" value="Approve">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `approve` will only be in the input data if the user clicks the Save button.  If they click the Decline button, it won't be.  Is that the issue?

Comment: No, sorry. So I just want to know which subbmit input was clicked by the user. Just the existance of the keys approve or decline in `self.request.POST` is needed. Currently that doesn't happen in `get_context_data()` when either are clicked. Only if I override post() is where I can see approve or decline in the POST dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after time away from it I've resolved it.

First I found that I had a Jquery script that was submitting the form with `$(this).submit();`. That, of course, means that it's not the submit input submitting it. So by simply removing that and `preventDefault();` it worked. The below is the culprit. It copies over the text to the relative hidden input. (It's so I have a text area that resizes automatically but still get the info to the server)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let form = $('#defForm')
    let descDiv = $("#description");
    let resoDiv = $('#resolution');
    form.one('submit', function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        let descTa = $("#id_description");
        let resoTa = $("#id_resolution");
        descTa.val(descDiv.text());
        resoTa.val(resoDiv.text());
        //$(this).submit();
    });
});
```

The second reason was that I needed a little extra configuration in the form.

I've added 2 fields to the `ModelForm` called `approve` and `decline`. Each are a `CharField` that aren't required and include a `TextInput` widget of which the attrs has `{'type': 'submit', 'value': 'Approve'}` (not exactly needed but good for if you just use `{{ form.approve }}` in the template).

Doing it this way not only shows the clicked submit in `self.request.POST` within `get_context_data()` but also the more useful `form_valid()`.

```
class DefinitionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    approve = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'submit', 'value': 'Approve'}), required=False)
    decline = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'submit', 'value': 'Decline'}), required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Definition
        fields = ['title', 'sup_sev', 'description', 'resolution']
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'resolution': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```